# Reading sms with Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm using this simple code:

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
Log.d("log", ""+cur.getCount());
```

The returned value is always zero. My app has READ_SMS permission of course. Is it an Oreo bug?

Edit: I tried even with `Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: Did this work on previous versions of Android?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: Upvoted.  I've heard about problems with Oreo, I'm not looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the same code with Android O with a sample app targeting SDK 26. Added `android.permission.READ_SMS` permission in `AndroidManifest`. And it worked.

Code :

```
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null);
Log.d("TAG", "Count: " + cur.getCount());
```

Comment: Is working fine if user are using default SMS app or any app that doesn't moves SMS from the default database, but it user is using Signal (or other "secure" app the query doesn't returns any data due to the database is empty